# I need some help in making this cloth simulation more realistic

Tags: modeling, cloth-simulation

I'm doing a cloth sim, where I have a plane acting as a backdrop, then falling like a curtain and revealing the true back plate. How could I make the curtain drop more realistic?

[image: the curtain falls]

https://drive.google.com/file/d/19vFh_NQxiJjMe6FzXpE3i3mPnR-lzdJO/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Your curtains look a bit stiff and sluggish. With a few tweaks, it could look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/an5K1.gif  Is this "more realistic"?

Comment: @Blunder yes in terms of speed and correct looking fold, but it seems to move around a bit longer than a curtain would after falling. any idea how to control that?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address raised the issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Answer (score 1):

One thing to check is the scale of your curtain. The physics engine takes size into account so it may look a little 'off' if your curtain isn't the size you're imagining it to be.

If all else fails (including changing the cloth properties as mentioned in the comments), you could try a neat little hack with Blender's time remapping feature: https://youtu.be/lxUBsZEfJNs?t=25

The same physics sim sped up makes it look heavier, slowed down makes it look lighter.

In the comments I see you mention that you're worried about how much the curtain moves around after it finishes its fall.

In the cache settings, you can choose the frame range for the simulation. The last frame you set is the last frame it'll calculate the simulation for. Basically, you can tell it when to stop physics'ing! Play your animation and find a point where it basically stops moving, and make that your last frame in the cache. When you bake the physics, it'll stop at that frame. This may look jarring if there was too much movement at the time, but depending on the animation and the camera angles, the viewer may not be able to see the curtain very much.